# Cosmos DB syntax to join to an aggregated sub-query

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm having a difficult time understanding the correct syntax and most efficient way to join queries together in a Cosmos DB query.

This query is giving me a list of records where the sourceSystemId is duplicated across more than 1 id.

```
SELECT d.NumRecs, d.sourceSystemId
            FROM (
                    SELECT
                    count(c.id) as NumRecs,
                    t.sourceSystem,
                    t.sourceSystemId
                    FROM Company AS c
                    JOIN t in c.primaryKeys
                    WHERE t.sourceSystem = "Netsuite" 
                    GROUP BY t.sourceSystem, t.sourceSystemId
                ) d
            WHERE d.NumRecs > 1
```

Example output:
[image]

I'd like to filter my main query (below), which exposes more relevant details, by the sourceSystemIds returned by the query above.

```
SELECT
        c.id,
        c.name,
        t.sourceSystem,
        t.sourceSystemId
        FROM Company AS c
        JOIN t in c.primaryKeys
     WHERE t.sourceSystem="Netsuite"
```

Example output:
[image]

Again, just to clarify, I want to add an additional condition to the WHERE clause in the 2nd query to filter by sourceSystemIds that are returned from the 1st query. Can someone please enlighten me further on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you explain with sample input and output data? for more clarity

Comment: What does **relevant details** mean? Can you explain in detail?

Comment: @Aswin after I've determined which sourceSystemIds are being duplicated (1st query above) then in the main query I need to expose the details of those records so the id, name, and type (I forgot to include that).

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] - including sample data , expected output, actual output, etc.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I've updated my original post with screenshots. Hopefully it's clearer what I'm trying to achieve. I just want to filter my 2nd query, which exposes additional details, by the records that are returned from my 1st query.

Comment: As Martin mentioned `NoSQL API does not support any syntax for using the result of one sub query as an input to another query`. Use any SDK to achieve the required output.

Answer (score 1):

Since the NoSQL API does not allow using the result of one sub-query as a filter to another, I did a workaround instead. I changed the SELECT of my aggregate query to the following:

```
SELECT VALUE d.sourceSystemId
        FROM (
                SELECT
                count(c.id) as NumRecs,
                t.sourceSystem,
                t.sourceSystemId
                FROM Company AS c
                JOIN t in c.primaryKeys
                WHERE t.sourceSystem = "Netsuite" 
                GROUP BY t.sourceSystem, t.sourceSystemId
            ) d
        WHERE d.NumRecs > 1
```

This provided me with a comma separated list of *sourceSystemIds* that were duplicated in the Company entity across different ids. There were only 111 unique values returned so I simply copy/pasted the list of values as a filter in the WHERE clause of my detail query as such (I've abbreviated the WHERE clause below):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(SELECT
        c.id,
        c.name,
        c.type,
        t.sourceSystem,
        t.sourceSystemId
        FROM Company AS c
        JOIN t in c.primaryKeys
WHERE t.sourceSystem = "Netsuite") a

WHERE a.sourceSystemId IN (
"196283",
    "507770",
    "13491",
    "507769",
    "13588"
)
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can use a subquery to get the relevant sourceSystemId values from the first query and then use those values as a filter in the second query.

```html
SELECT
    c.id,
    c.name,
    t.sourceSystem,
    t.sourceSystemId
FROM Company c
JOIN t IN c.primaryKeys
WHERE t.sourceSystemId IN (
    SELECT d.sourceSystemId
    FROM (
        SELECT
            COUNT(c.id) AS NumRecs,
            t.sourceSystem,
            t.sourceSystemId
        FROM Company c
        JOIN t IN c.primaryKeys
        WHERE t.sourceSystem = "Netsuite"
        GROUP BY t.sourceSystem, t.sourceSystemId
    ) d
    WHERE d.NumRecs > 1
)
```

Here the innermost query retrieves the sourceSystemId values with a count greater than 1. the middle query (aliased as d) filters the results to only include those with NumRecs greater than 1 and the outer query then filters the main query based on the sourceSystemId values obtained from the middle query.

Comment: This is not valid syntax for CosmosDB. `Syntax error, incorrect syntax near 'SELECT'` The NoSQL API does not support any syntax for using the result of one sub query as an input to another query